# Error with siunitx package, charter package, \ohm, and detect-all option

Tags: symbols, siunitx

I have a problem when trying to use the `\ohm` unit from the `siunitx` package when the `detect-all` option in the `siunitx` package is enabled, and the `charter` package is also used.

When `detect-all` is enabled and the `charter` package is used, the `\ohm` symbol will not show correctly (shows as a black box instead).

Miniumum working example (MWE) below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

This works: \SI{10}{\milli\ohm}.

\sisetup{detect-all,}
Now this does not work:  \SI{10}{\milli\ohm}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at this [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376886/141947). My proposal direclty comes from there

Basically the `ohm` symbol is not provided by the  `charter` package, so you have to provide it another way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{arev}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{mdbch}

\begin{document}

This works: \SI{10}{\milli\ohm}.

\sisetup{detect-all,}
Now this does not work:  \SI{10}{\milli\ohm}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. Your solution worked for my MWE, but gave errors when used in my larger document, probably due to inconsistencies with other packages. I'll try and find out what, and will update here if I do.

In the meantime, as an alternative solution, I've moved from using the charter package to the XCharter package instead, which provides support for Greek letters.